# unable to add a js/css file to www folder in phonegap in xcode4

Tags: javascript, cordova

I've started coding in phonegap, I could get the helloworld project running, but the problem is that, I'm not able to add another js/css file to the www folder, and when I somehow add the file I'm not able to reference them. So can anybody suggest me a proper way to add a js/css file and how to reference it from the index.html file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had the same problem, I used to create the files in the project folder itself instead of Xcode. Now i use build.phonegap.com thus eliminating the need for xcode/ios